# Quickblox 422 No recipient issue using Android SDK

Tags: android, quickblox

I am using `Quickblox` Android Chat SDK for my chat module. I have implemented whatever the process stated in `Quickblox` Site. I was able to register,login and creating session to the `Quickblox` programmatically and able to chat and chat history successfully. I got struck for some users, I am not able to chat as I am getting `422 error "'{"errors":{"base":["No recipients. At least one user should be subscribed for GCM (Android Push) (through SDK or REST API)"]}}'"`. But for some users, I am not facing any problem. Please suggest me the solution for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

In means that a user doesn't have a push subscription, so he can't receive pushes

follow this guide to subscribe a user to receive push notifications http://quickblox.com/developers/SimpleSample-messages_users-android#Giving_a_user_a_Push_Notification_subscription

Comment: I find in Quickblox Admin Panel whenever I get 422 error "'{"errors":{"base":["No recipients. At least one user should be subscribed for GCM (Android Push) (through SDK or REST API)"]}}'", opponent's subscription will be disappeared. Could you please suggest me why the subscription of some users disappears at some times?

Comment: If 2 users use the same device then previous user will be unsubscribed automatically

Comment: I could not trace 422 error "'{"errors":{"base":["No recipients. At least one user should be subscribed for GCM (Android Push) (through SDK or REST API)"]}}'" as to in which areas it is coming, even when two users logged in separate devices. In most of the cases, I am getting 422 error when the user is promoted with Push Notification. I find, after some time the Subscription of one user gets deleted during the chat between two users. It is not for all users in general. Observed only for some users.

Comment: Apart from this issue, we have observed two more issues happening here and there while getting push notifications. 1. erro when join group chat:com.quickblox.core.exception.QBResponseException:No response received within reply timeout. Timeout was 5000ms (~5s). 2. error when join group chat:com.quickblox.core.exception.QBResponseException:XMPPError:registration-required - auth. Please suggest the solution for these issues.